Can Python threads and queues be used to transfer data within in a PyQt5 QApplication?
My Use Case is:

I have a Non-Blocking Python module that writes data to a file
it uses threading.Thread to handle the Non-Blocking requirement
it uses Queue.queue to handle protecting the data that is supplied to the thread
The User must be able to import and use this module in both:

another Python Package and
a PyQt5 QApplication offering a GUI for the module



I would like to know if there are any potential issues with passing data from the QApplication to the Python thread via the queue. For example,a QPushButton called "Save Data" connects to a PyQtSlot that puts the data into the queue. Within the Python thread, the queue is read and the data is written.
This has already been implemented for awhile now and is working.

Queues are meant to be thread safe, so adding data to a queue from the main thread is not an issue, unless its write access is locked in some way.
